# When implementing a simple shell interpretor, what is the best strategy to handle parenthesis?

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a simple c shell, and I've gotten most of it down. I now just need to handle parenthesis. So, for example, if I have a statement that looks like this:

`(echo hi && echo hello) | (echo world || (echo hello ; echo sun))`

The output should be:

```
world
sun
```

I'm not sure what the general strategy is for handling parenthesis for shell commands.

Comment: The fastest strategy is to define your syntax as a proper grammar and then use a parser generator to generate a so called "push parser" (for example https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Push-Decl ).

Comment: Aside: by "a simple C shell", do you mean a csh-family shell, or do you just mean "a shell written in C"? The phrase "C shell" is a term of the art, and refers to a category of shells of which [avoidance is strongly advised](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt). Actually, reading that link is going to be worthwhile -- one of the core arguments there is that 90% of csh's woes come from having an ad-hoc hand-generated parser rather than one built from a formal language description, and that's a lesson anyone writing a shell (or other language parser) should take to heart.

Comment: ...that said, in terms of dealing with parsing nested contexts, that's really a generic parsing question, rather than anything meaningfully shell-specific. Picking a good parser generator is the real trick here -- bison/yacc have been around forever (and lots of university textbooks teach their use) but are not at all the only options available. Anyhow -- learn to write a parser, *any* parser, and this question will be moot.

Comment: Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators as a place to start down the rabbit hole. (Or, better, a 300-level CSCI course; in the university system I attended, parsing was taught under a course titled "Compiler Design").

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys! THis is some good material to get started with